# Can you give me a case where I would need to wait for a callback to complete in a unit test?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, tdd

I can't think of a case where, in JavaScript, I would need a unit test to wait for a callback completion.

Unit testing is about testing the smallest parts, the units. So I would write tests:

- for the function I'm testing
- for the callback function
- to check the function calls the callback correctly using a mock (or spy)

But I see in testing frameworks such as Jasmine or Mocha that they allow for asynchronous testing. I guess it makes sense in integration tests (or BDD) but not unit tests. Do you have examples of unit tests that would need asynchronous testing?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you that asynchronous testing is more relevant for behavioral driven development (BDD) tests where you are creating real world use cases rather than going through a list of methods per object and checking they perform as expected.

As for unit testing, I would say there is still a place for asynchronous tests. Say you are testing a class and one of the methods performs an AJAX request to a REST entry point in order to get some data and return a result (for example authenticate a user), this is still a single unit of computation, ie:

```
Auth.validate({user: "smithj", pass: "mypwd"});
```

However if you perform your test synchronously you would not be able to check that the method has executed correctly as you would be checking for a result before obtaining a response from the remote entry point.

Comment: This is a good example but I think this is already a integration test as you're testing both the JS code and the REST API at the same time. Your test is dependant on the REST API so it's not a unit test anymore.

Comment: Bit late to the party but actually I have to agree with Steven - for example if you were using [https://github.com/appendto/jquery-mockjax] Mockjax to mock Ajax calls then it is a 100% pure unit test...